# Why does PrincipalPermission with a deny securityaction still allow access?

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, identity, principal

I have been playing around with identity and principal when I noticed that the method I added

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Deny, Role = "Admin")]
```

with an identity of

```
GenericIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("JC", "Type1");
GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { "Admin", "User" });
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

still gets invoked without throwing SecurityException as it would if it had a Demand security action.

In fact even if I have misspelled the Role like so

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Deny, Role = "asad")]
```

It would still allow me to invoke the method without throwing much of a fit

The question is, why?

My whole code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenericIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("JC", "Type1");
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { "Admin", "User" });
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            UsePrincipal();
        }

        static void UsePrincipal()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
            try
            {
                DevWork();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Bad!");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Deny, Role = "Admin")]
        static void DevWork() // Will be executed no matter what the role is
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Good!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Which version of .NET you are using?

Comment: .net framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in documentation of [SecurityAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction(v=vs.110).aspx) that `Deny` is obsolete and:

> In the .NET Framework 4, runtime support has been removed for
>   enforcing the Deny, RequestMinimum, RequestOptional, and RequestRefuse
>   permission requests. These requests should not be used in code that is
>   based on .NET Framework 4 or later.

Since you are using .NET 4.5.2 - your `Deny` request is simply being ignored.